# Getting a 404 on a redirect from a button in an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, actionmailer

I'm using rails to send an email to log in a user through a link. In that email I have a button and link that both use the same url but with the button I'm getting a 404 error while using google or yahoo's main site to view the email. While using third party email portals I don't seem to have this issue. The link works in all circumstances.

In the view for the email template, I'm using the `button_to` tag for the button that will redirect the user to the site to log them in. Which I noticed puts the button into a form. So I was wondering if this was a safety measure by google and yahoo to prevent potential threats and I need to refactor to just have a button without the form element, or could it be an issue with my code?

Comment: I believe I've found the issue. That the form is submitting a post request. Not sure why that would be causing a 404 after redirecting the user in a new page while using the same url as the link. But I'm thinking changing the method to use a get request instead could work

Comment: The whole point of using `button_to` is that it creates a form so that you can send POST, PATCH or DELETE requests without relying on Rails UJS. While you can make a form that sends GET requests by explicitly setting the method attribute you should probally just be using a link in the first place and using CSS to style it to look like a button.

Comment: You would usually only use a form for GET requests when you actually need a form for interactive content like inputs and I would guess that it can be quite problematic with emails as clients may block it. If you want an example of what you should be doing then look at how Devise solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I ended up using ```link_to``` to create a link and style it into looking like button, like you mentioned in your first comment. Again thanks for the help